# detecting hold event in webview on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently working on a web browser app mainly targeting win rt in Windows phone 8.1. I'm now trying to figure out how to detect the hold event when a user holds down a link or image in webview and display a context menu.

How would I go about doing this? How would I detect the event in wp8.1? I know I'll have to invoke script but what is the c# to detect the event? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `Holding` event attribute of the UI element?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke script in `WebView` for binding gesture event in javascript first. Read this:[MSGestureHold | onmsgesturehold event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465866.aspx)

Then you should use `window.external.notify` in the `MSGestureHold` event handler above to notify your `WebView` that `Hold` event is triggered.

But [WinRT 8.1 WebView is disabled `scriptnotify` in non-certificated websites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx)(read the remarks), so you should find a solution to fix this issue. [Here is my solution.](http://blog.edi-c.com/post/a-solution-for-any-hosts-to-notify-winrt-81-webview.html)

Or you can [download my demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv2sq7qt9ybuopz/Control_WebView.zip) directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Eddie I've been looking into it and I cant seem to figure out how to get the MSGesture hold event to fire from the link you suggested. Sorry Im kind of a beginner when it comes to DOM and Windows Phone