# Handling Gestures in a Windows Phone WebView App

Tags: webview, touch, windows-phone-8.1, gesture

I am trying to build a WP 8.1 App which I have created using the WebView Template in Visual Studio.

I want to listen for touch gestures to implement site navigation and related stuff, but being new to Windows Phone, I am unable to receive any gesture based event.

I've read that WebView by design does not support gestures, so I tried listening for ManipulationStarted event in the Page control which hosts the Webview element, but I am getting no calls to this.

Also I've enabled ManipulationMode=All in the Page properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can read my answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25283988/1708474). You can use javascript to notify your code-behind to do the gesture things.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that the javascript on the website itself is unable to recognize the movement. I think it is because the DirectManipulation API handles any movement of the pointer itself, so that pointermoved events in javascript will no longer be triggered